# object not returning from function (VBA Excel) (I get "Object variable or With block variable not set" when trying to use the returned object)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that creates and saves a Workbook, and a subroutine that calls this function. The function should return the Workbook, but it doesn't appear to be doing so, even though I am using `set <functionname> = <the new Workbook object>` at the end of the function.

Here is the function that creates the workbook:

```
Function CreateandSaveNewWorkbook(filePath) As Workbook
    Dim newWb As Workbook
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
    ' Saves the new workbook with a specific name in specified location
    newWb.SaveAs filePath
    Set CreateAndSaveNewWrokbook = newWb
End Function
```

And here's a stripped down version of my subroutine that calls the function:

```
Sub mySub(fullFilePath)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = CreateandSaveNewWorkbook(fullFilePath)
    
    Dim wbname As String
    wbname = wb.name
    MsgBox (wbname)
End Sub
```

I am able to call `CreateandSaveNewWorkbook`; it creates the workbook without issue. However, once I get to `wbname = wb.name` it fails with `Object variable or With block variable not set`.

I have tried activating the workbook but it makes no difference.

I am very new to VBA, and after spending some hours on this, I can't figure this out. There are multiple SO with similar questions, but the error in those is because they did not use the `Set` keyword, which is not what is happening here. I imagine I am doing something very obviously wrong, that I will feel very foolish about once I discover it. Can anyone help me see what that is?

Comment: There is a typo here: `Set CreateAndSaveNewW**or**kbook = newWb` .

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe that. I guess I am spoiled on compilers that tell me if I'm trying to use a variable that hasn't been declared. I'm curious why the error didn't actually come on that line? And why it allowed the code to progress beyond that line?

Comment: Add `Option explicit` to the beginning of the module - then you will receive an error on debugging.

Comment: Flashbacks to perl with `use strict; use warnings;`. Will use this going forward. Thanks!

Comment: You can configure VBA to automatically add the `Option Explicit` statement to new module: on the tools menu, click options > select editor tab > check "Require Variable Declaration"

Comment: Perfect - was just looking for the best way to do this. Just curious - are there any other useful Options to set that you might recommend to someone completely new to VBA? Or is this the big one to look out for?

Comment: Yes - that's the big one.

Comment: Another useful one is to turn off the automatic syntax check. That stops the editor from interfering with that irritating messagebox each time you make a slight mistake. It'll still color your line red.

Comment: @jkpieterse THANK YOU. That has been annoying me to no end! Slows everything down.